# Speeding a bytes pattern scanning c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, design-patterns, memory

I coded a program that scan for bad code injected in my process and i would like to speed it up if possible.
I changed the code to scan by 4 bytes at a time instead of 1 byte and using mask AND for hazzard bytes, but its still slow.
AntiCheats and especially Anti Virus have a super fast algorithm.
Can someone point me in the right direction of scanning fast?

```
AddSignatureToDB("75??83FB5375??81FE890000000F84????????E9????????83FB4F75", ERROR_SIGID_1);

void AddSignatureToDB(char* szSig, DWORD dwSigID)
{
    char szHex[]        = "0x00";
    int iSigLen = lstrlenA(szSig) / 2;
    int iPadding = iSigLen % 4;

    BYTE* mSigData = new BYTE[iSigLen+iPadding];
    BYTE* mSigMask = new BYTE[iSigLen+iPadding];

    for (int i = 0; i < iSigLen; i++)
    {
        mSigData[i] = 0x00;
        mSigMask[i] = 0x00;

        if (szSig[i * 2] != '?')
        {
            szHex[3] = szSig[i * 2];
            mSigData[i] |= (strtoul(szHex, NULL, 0) << 4 & 0xF0);
            mSigMask[i] |= 0xF0;
        }

        if (szSig[i * 2 + 1] != '?')
        {
            szHex[3] = szSig[i * 2 + 1];
            mSigData[i] |= (strtoul(szHex, NULL, 0) & 0x0F);
            mSigMask[i] |= 0x0F;
        }
    }

    if (iPadding > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iPadding; i++)
        {
            mSigData[iSigLen+i] = 0x00;
            mSigMask[iSigLen+i] = 0x00;
        }
    }

    this->SigDB[this->iNumSig].mSigBytes = mSigData;
    this->SigDB[this->iNumSig].mSigMasks = mSigMask;
    this->SigDB[this->iNumSig].iNumBytes = iSigLen+iPadding;
    this->SigDB[this->iNumSig].dwSigID = dwSigID;
    this->iNumSig++;
}

bool ScanBlockForSig(BYTE* pBuffer, int iBufSize, T_SigHolder* Sig)
{
    bool bFound = true;
    bool bFound2 = false;

    for (int i = (DWORD)pBuffer; i < ((DWORD)pBuffer + iBufSize - Sig->iNumBytes); i++)
    {
        bFound = true;

        int iStepped = 0;

        while (iStepped < Sig->iNumBytes)
        {
            DWORD dwMask = *(DWORD*)&Sig->mSigMasks[iStepped];
            DWORD dwPart1 = *(DWORD*)&Sig->mSigBytes[iStepped];
            DWORD dwPart2 = *(DWORD*)(i + iStepped) & dwMask;

            if (dwPart1 != dwPart2)
            {
                bFound = false;
                break;
            }

            iStepped += 4;
        }

        if (bFound == true)
        {
            dwAddressFound = (DWORD)i;
            bFound2 = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    return bFound2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem of pattern searching is both fascinating and, fortunately, well defined. We define the search string as length n, the number of patterns to search as p, and the combined length of the patterns m.

You can think of string searching as being a specialism of pattern scanning. When you know that, it unlocks well known algorithms such as Boyer Moore which has worst-case of O(n+m) if the pattern does not occur in the search text, which is faster than the naive approach at O(nm).

The sub-category of algorithms you are looking for here is multiple pattern searching. For this, you should investigate how the Rabin Karp algorithm works (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm), which is slower than Boyer Moore, but can be extended to support multiple pattern searching in worst-case O(nm) with space O(p).

However the fastest algorithm I have used for solving this problem is Aho Corasick (https://github.com/bigdatadev/aho_corasick). It is not the most memory efficient algorithm at O(m), but it is the fastest in terms of worst-case performance O(n+m).

Comment: The problem is i need to ignore some bytes in the middle of the string.

Comment: And even tough u called it string, that string at the first line of code is converted into a byte array which is then compared to the memory blocks in RAM.

Comment: If you need to ignore bytes in the middle of the string just split it into two strings and search left then right with aho corasick. It will still be as fast, and faster than any other method.

Comment: is Aho Corasick better than Boyer Moore? or it has any disadvantages/limatations we should be aware of?

Comment: also what about horspool?